# why is GWT dev mode "restart server" failing?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

GWT Dev mode works fine, until I try to "Restart Server".  At that point I get a "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/el/BeanELResolver" exception.

This is running using maven, where I had to set:

true

which as it suggests, puts the GWT classes at the front of the classpath to avoid such problems with jars full of placeholders.  I'm speculating that perhaps the restart isn't observing that flag, but haven't confirmed it.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, operator error: the "true" above was a mangled reference to the maven "gwtSdkFirstInClasspath" tag, which was set to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<runClasspathExcludes>
   <runClasspathExclude>javaee-web-api-6.0.jar</runClasspathExclude>
</runClasspathExcludes>
```

That tidbit in the gwt-maven-plugin configuration section looks like the trick.